# Append filenames to csv-file if matching id

Tags: text-processing, csv-simple

I have two files

file1

```
159211;exampleimage002.JPG
159212;example.jpg
159212;example with space.jpg
...
```

file2

```
13;"OVET";"O1";"OVET/ULKO-OVET";159212;"JELDWEN BASIC 0015 9*21 VASEN";"KPL";1;345;1;0;"Toinen testituote";
13;"OVET";"O1";"OVET/ULKO-OVET";159211;"JELDWEN BASIC 0015 9*21 OIKEA";"KPL";1;345;1;0;"Myös rivinvaihdot siirtyvät";
...
```

What I need is to add the image names as a new column, multiple image files separated with "|". ID must match, for example 159212 (file1 first column and file2 5th column). I tried this using awk, but failed miserably.

Wanted output (file3), only difference is the last column:

```
13;"OVET";"O1";"OVET/ULKO-OVET";159212;"JELDWEN BASIC 0015 9*21 VASEN";"KPL";1;345;1;0;"Toinen testituote";"exampleimage002.JPG";
13;"OVET";"O1";"OVET/ULKO-OVET";159211;"JELDWEN BASIC 0015 9*21 OIKEA";"KPL";1;345;1;0;"Myös rivinvaihdot siirtyvät";"example.jpg|example with space.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
awk -F\; '
  NR==FNR {
    if (a[$1]=="") {
      a[$1]="\""$2
    } else {
      a[$1]=a[$1]"|"$2
    }
    next;
  }
  {
    print $0 a[$5] "\""
  }
  ' file1 file2 > file3
```

Note: this assumes there's at least one match for each ID - otherwise you'll likely get a spurious trailing close quote. If that's an issue, you could add a test for non-emptyness of `a[$5]` before printing.

Comment: This works, I added a test to check non-emptyness too, thanks!